# xslt moving child attribute to parent

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

Input:

```
    <book>
     <chapter href="..">
      <topicref chunk="to-content" href"..">

      </topicref>
      <topicref chunk="to-content" href"..">

      </topicref>
     </chapter>
    </book>
```

Output:

```
    <book>
     <chapter chunk="to-content" href="..">
      <topicref href"..">

      </topicref>
      <topicref href"..">

      </topicref>
     </chapter>
    </book>
```

I cannot use `xsl:attribute name="chunk">to-content</xsl:attribute>` because it throws "creating an attribute here will fail if previous instructions create any children." warning and then error. I understand that as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes). Any workaround?

Using XSLT 2.0 with Saxon 9. (just getting the hang of XSLT/ S.O. still). Sorry if this is too broad but any help in any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and output you get that allow us to reproduce the problem. Your current snippet is a single template matching `book` elements but not even creating a copy of any of them, then processing any `chapter` children, again not copying any, but then creating an attribute `chunk`. Given that snippet you would only output attributes which does not make much sense.

Comment: Have edited the question. My code was useless here. I'm creating the book, chapter and everything just alright. Not posting here because its huge. So any help/ thoughts will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add an attribute to the `chapter` element, it would be best to have a template matching the `chapter` element - along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="chunk">to-content</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Similarly, to remove the `chunk` attribute from `topicref`:

```
<xsl:template match="topicref/@chunk"/>
```

Comment: This is simple and works. Needed to edit a little to integrate in my code but thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- If the chapter contains a topicref with chunk="to-content", set chunk to-content on the chapter unless it's already there.-->
    <xsl:if test=".//topicref/@chunk = 'to-content' and not(@chunk='to-content')">
      <xsl:attribute name="chunk">to-content</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- Copy all chapter attributes -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topicref">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Copy every attribute except chunk="to-content" -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name() = 'chunk' and . = 'to-content')]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```