# Merge Child Into Unknown Parent By Name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to merge a Child element to its Parent, moving all attributes from the Child to the Parent and then removing the Child aftwards.

Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Blocks>
  <Block ID="OA00" Name="Generic">
    <Design ID="DA00" />
  </Block>
  <Block ID="OA01" Name="WildStar" DenyChange="true">
    <Design ID="DA00" />
    <Coordinate X="50" Y="60" />
  </Block>
  <Block ID="OA02" Name="Eraser" />
</Blocks>
```

Into this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Blocks>
      <Block ID="OA00" Name="Generic">
        <Design ID="DA00" />
      </Block>
      <Block ID="OA01" Name="WildStar" DenyChange="true" X="50" Y="60" >
        <Design ID="DA00" />
      </Block>
      <Block ID="OA02" Name="Eraser" />
    </Blocks>
```

However the name of the Parent isn't always "Block", it could be anything but the Child's name is always "Coordinate".

This is for serializing and deserializing a vb.net class where Coordinate is a structure inside the class.

[This one was the closest i came to what i wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704005/xslt-moving-child-attribute-to-parent) but it doesn't solve the unknown Parent name.

This is what i have now but i'm novice at XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name(..)" />
    <xsl:if test="*[local-name() = 'Coordinate']">
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|Coordinate/@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Coordinate"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was hoping that the "if" test could ensure that it would only copy Coordinate attributes to the Parent but i'm getting a blank output when [i try to run it through here.](http://xslttest.appspot.com/)

To summarize, if a node has a child of name "Coordinate" everything in that node and it's attributes should be move to its Parent and then the "Coordinate" node should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, this stylesheet with a small modification of the identity rule and another empty rule to discard `Coordinate` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Coordinate/@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Coordinate"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Blocks>
  <Block ID="OA00" Name="Generic">
    <Design ID="DA00"/>
  </Block>
  <Block ID="OA01" Name="WildStar" DenyChange="true" X="50" Y="60">
    <Design ID="DA00"/>    
  </Block>
  <Block ID="OA02" Name="Eraser"/>
</Blocks>
```

Comment: This seems to work as intended, i'll have to do some more testing to be completely sure, then i'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a template that matches any element that has a `Coordinate` as a child...

```
<xsl:template match="*[Coordinate]">
```

Then you can just copy that element, and add in the co-ordinate attributes too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[Coordinate]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|Coordinate/@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Coordinate"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that in your original XSLT you have two templates matching the same thing (`node()` in this case) which would be considered to be an error. Processors could either flag the error, or pick the last matching templates

Comment: This turns attributes into elements of all blocks that don't have a "Coordinate" child
but it does seem to do the right thing for that one parent node, just have to try to tinker with it some more

Comment: You are right. My apologies. I had missed out the matching of the attribute from the identity template, which I have now corrected. 
Alejandro's answer is more concise though.